# Querying dynamodb on index which has 1 Million records

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way at all to query on the `global secondary index` of a dynamodb table to fetch, say, `1000` records at a time and return the next set on the next query. I have a `java application` which queries the table and fetches all the records associated to it and that is causing heap space error on my EC2 instance. Is there a way to parallelize dynamodb query operation like `Kinesis checkpointer`. Below is how I am querying.

```
    DynamoDBQueryExpression<RecordsTest> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<RecordsTest>()
                .withHashKeyValues(test).withConsistentRead(false);
        List<RecordsTest> test  = mapper.query(RecordsTest.class, queryExpression); for (RecordsTest tst : test) {
            System.out.println(" record not found");}
```

Also, I have tried using the `QuerySpec` option but this returns the same set of elements from the table when I specify the limit of items to return. i want the returned items to be those which were not returned earlier.

Comment: A scan will return a paginated list -- afaik that's already doing what you want behind the scenes.

Comment: I want to query keeping in mind the throughput i provisioned on my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query API performs sequential reads on DynamoDB partitions, starting at the partition key you provided in KeyConditions. If you use [sharding with prefixes on the partition key](http://www.slideshare.net/InfoQ/amazon-dynamodb-design-patterns-best-practices) as part of your schema, you can run query API in parallel on each shard of a partition key. You need to set ExclusiveStartKey on subsequent Query calls using the LastEvaluatedKey of the previous call, if you want to avoid returning the same results.